# Isolate data from brackets in JSON Parsing request

Tags: swift

I'm testing how to get data from an API and I get the following output:

```
WeatherResponse(temperature: 0.0, humidity: 0.0, pressure: 0.0)
```

How can I get the data printed out separately, like this:

temperature: 0.0
humidity: 0.0
pressure: 0.0

This the code I have from a playground:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

guard let url = URL(string: "https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=524901&appid=b1b15e88fa797225412429c1c50c122a1") else {
    fatalError("Incorrect URL")
}

struct WeatherResponse: Decodable {
    var temperature: Double = 0
    var humidity: Double = 0
    var pressure: Double = 0
    
    private enum WeatherResponseKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case main
    }
    
    private enum MainKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case temperature = "temp"
        case humidity
        case pressure
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        if let weatherResponseContainer = try? decoder.container(keyedBy: WeatherResponseKeys.self) {
            
            if let mainContainer = try? weatherResponseContainer.nestedContainer(keyedBy: MainKeys.self, forKey: .main) {
                self.temperature = try mainContainer.decode(Double.self, forKey: .temperature)
                self.humidity = try mainContainer.decode(Double.self, forKey: .humidity)
                self.pressure = try mainContainer.decode(Double.self, forKey: .pressure)
            }
        }
    }
}


URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, _ in
    if let data = data {
        let weatherResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(WeatherResponse.self, from: data)
        if let weatherResponse = weatherResponse {
            print(weatherResponse)
        }
    }
} .resume()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically have two options:

a) print the individual components, like so:

```
print("temperature: \(weatherResponse.temperature) humidity: \(weatherResponse.humidity) pressure: \(weatherResponse.pressure)")
```

or b), make `WeatherResponse` conform to `CustomStringConvertible` and implement `description`:

```
extension WeatherResponse: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
       "temperature: \(temperature) humidity: \(humidity) pressure: \(pressure)"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll go with the first one :) It's more modular for my case now

Comment: Btw I know this is outside of the question, but why am I getting 0 on the values instead of the actual value?

Comment: No Idea. Probably worth it to ask in a separate question.